# Why does the gradle build process strip out my Application and Activity classes?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I have an application that's written with Unity. It uses a custom Application and Activity class. Previously this has worked just fine but I've recently switched to using gradle to perform the build instead of Unity's deprecated internal build process. My Application and Activity classes are located in a library that's in the form of an aar file. The custom classes are referenced from a the  and  tags of a custom AndroidManifest.

I can see that the classes are present in the aar. I can see that the generated AndroidManifest references these class. I can see the dependency on this library in the generated `build.gradle` file. I can tell that the build process is actually referencing this library in some form. However, these classes are not present in the resulting APK, resulting in a crash on launch.

I do not have proguard or anything similar enabled. I can tell that this is a new problem because older versions of the APK do have those classes. What could be causing these classes to not be included in the resulting APK?

Comment: Have you unzipped the apk and decompiled the dex to verify they are not in there? Can you post the exact crash log?

Answer (score 0):

The package that contained those classes had the same name as the one generated by Unity. I changed the package name and everything seems to be working now.